# Role of node.js in appium server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-services, appium

Can anyone tell me in simple words what is actually node.js ?

I am learning "Appium" and came across it. Its mentioned as "Appium at its core is a webserver written in Node.js that exposes a REST API".

I don't know what exactly is Node.js , JSON ,Bootstrap.js, REST API , Webservices..
I browsed the above but I couldn't get it exactly in detail.
Attached image of appium architecture
[image]

Can anyone let me know in simple words what exactly are these..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform runtime environment for developing server-side Web applications

JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is used to represent objects with complex data structures. It is used primarily to transfer data between a server and a client on the web.

So JSON is something which communicates via key value pair structure, eg it takes key-Mobile device name, value-actual mobile device.

In such way appium server interacts with the mobile device/emulator to send/recieve commands and perform required actions